# slow creation of fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

So I have a fragment which launches really slowly like it skips 150+ frames.
I am trying to setup ViewPager inside of the fragment and add onPageChangeListener which disables swipe after swiping to a certain direction.

The problem is that it really slows down the fragment loading speed. I tried moving it to a separate thread and AsyncTask but its still slow.

Fragment:

```java
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    public View mView;


    public SettingsFragment() {
       
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    @Deprecated
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings,container,false);
        this.mView=rootview;
        Task task=new Task();
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        return rootview;
        
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            final CustomViewPager viewPager = mView.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new Adapter(getFragmentManager()));
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    if (position == 0) {
                        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

The xml layout file for fragment:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:background="#fff" android:animationCache="true"
                                                   android:id="@+id/SettingsFragmentContainer"
                                                   android:drawingCacheQuality="high">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/SettingsActivityToolbar" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
                android:text="Settings"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/Settings_textview"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText"/>
        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="46dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/settings_icon_back"
                android:id="@+id/backPressButton"
                android:rotation="180" android:backgroundTint="#fff"
                android:background="@null"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/SettingsActivityToolbar"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:onClick="click" android:drawingCacheQuality="high"/>
        <TextView
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:id="@+id/linebreak1" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backPressButton" android:background="#A1A8AC"/>
        <Switch
                android:text="Test Test"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="47dp" android:id="@+id/switch4"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:thumbTint="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
                android:trackTint="@drawable/switch_track_selector" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/backPressButton" tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp" android:id="@+id/linebreak2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp" android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:background="#A1A8AC"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch4"/>
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="67dp" android:id="@+id/update"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch4" android:onClick="onClickUpdate"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Current Version 1.0.1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_height="0dp" android:id="@+id/enter_version"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/update"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp" android:layout_marginEnd="206dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/update"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Check Update"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/update_textview"
                android:textAppearance="@style/ActionBar.nameText" android:layout_marginEnd="228dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/update" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/update"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <com.testapp.test2.CustomViewPager
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/ViewPager" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapter.java

```java
public class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);

    }
    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position==0){

            return new BlankFragment();
        }
        if(position==1){

            return new SettingsFragment();
        }

            return null;
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
2020-10-15 07:51:34.234 14029-14034/com.testapp.test2 I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
2020-10-15 07:51:35.302 14029-14029/com.testapp.test2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 165 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-10-15 07:51:50.250 14029-14034/com.testapp.test2 I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=502KB, data=324KB
2020-10-15 07:51:50.252 14029-14034/com.testapp.test2 I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=501KB, data=287KB
2020-10-15 07:51:51.006 14029-14034/com.testapp.test2 I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=503KB, data=297KB
2020-10-15 07:51:51.007 14029-14034/com.testapp.test2 I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=503KB, data=297KB
2020-10-15 07:51:51.007 14029-14034/com.testapp.test2 I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
2020-10-15 07:51:51.886 14029-14034/com.testapp.test2 I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
2020-10-15 07:51:54.868 14029-14029/com.testapp.test2 I/TouchMotionHandler: handler onDetached
```

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setMenuVisibility(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:189)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:335)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6767)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6767)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6767)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6767)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6767)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:898)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22251)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2500)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1564)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1826)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1446)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6954)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:925)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:737)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:669)
2020-10-16 00:56:36.824 14663-14663/com.testapp.test2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

Comment: The way I read this is you have a `SettingsFragement` that displays a `ViewPager` that loads the same `SettingsFragement` as page 2, which contains another instance of the same `ViewPager`, in a never ending loop, which would make it slow. Why is `SettingsFragement` recursive in this fashion?

Comment: If I remove ```SettingsFragment``` from the adapter i get nullpointer exception. I added the logcat above. Help me @Andrew..

Comment: How did you remove the `SettingsFragment`? did you just comment out the `return new SettingsFragment();` line? If you did that would certainly generate a NullPointerException unless you also changed the `getCount()` return to `1` or you could have replaced that line with `return new BlankFragment();`

Comment: I did change the ```getCount()``` to 1 but it still gives me NullPointerException. @Andrew

Comment: And replacing ```return new SettingsFragment()``` with ```return new BlankFragment()``` will create another ```BlankFragment``` because i set ```viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)``` in my OnCreateView of ```SettingsFragment``` @Andrew

Comment: Nevermind If I change the build type to release its super fast. Its like magic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the build type from debug to release.